# python 3 tkinter images

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have set up a Rasbperry Pi 3 and using Python 3. I can take images but need to refresh them on screen. VERY new to tkinker. I have some code but would like to know how to place a nice sized image on the canvas and to refresh it when one of my buttons is pressed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tkinter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import picamera
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageTk




def startup():
    def callback(a):

        if a==4:
            thiscolour="yellow"
            camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg')
        if a==2:
            thiscolour="red"
        lbl.configure(text=thiscolour+" has been pressed")



        path = "/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg"
        img = Image.open(path) 
        new_width  = 400
        new_height = 600
        #img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save('thisimage.jpg') 
        path="thisimage.jpg"
        path="thisimage.jpg"
        image = Image.open(path)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        panel.configure(image=photo)
        panel.pack()




    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    path = "/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg"
    img = Image.open(path) 
    new_width  = 400
    new_height = 600
    img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save('thisimage.jpg') 
    path="thisimage.jpg"
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    buttonyellow = 4
    buttonred = 2
    t=0
    GPIO.setup(buttonyellow, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(buttonred, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
    window=tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Photobooth")
    window.geometry("1000x800")
    lbl=tkinter.Label(window,text="Instructions")
    ent=tkinter.Entry(window)
    btn=tkinter.Button(window,text="Press here", bg='red')
    btn=tkinter.Button(window,text="Click me",bg='red',command=callback)
    btn.pack()
    lbl.pack()
    ent.pack()
    btn.pack()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(buttonyellow, GPIO.FALLING, callback=callback, bouncetime=100)   
    GPIO.add_event_detect(buttonred, GPIO.FALLING, callback=callback, bouncetime=100)   
    path="thisimage.jpg"
    image = Image.open(path)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel = tkinter.Label(window, image = img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    window.mainloop()    


startup()
```

Comment: `Button( ..., command=function_name)` and  `canvas.create_image(...)`

Comment: better find some tutorial -http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Comment: Thanks. I found plenty of tutorials but I just seem to be stuck on this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is displayed in a label. The update button triggers a command that first take the new picture (or whatever you want, I haven't written this part of the code), then loads the new image and finally updates the image inside the label using `configure(image=...)`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self) # create window
        # load initial image
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("path/to/image"))
        # display it in a label
        self.label = tk.Label(self, image=self.img)
        self.label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        tk.Button(self, text="Update", command=self.update_image).pack()

        self.mainloop()

    def update_image(self):
        # code to capture new image here
        # ...
        # load new image
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("path/to/image"))
        # update label image
        self.label.configure(image=self.img)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```